# How can I type check uuid and date_time in an entity generated from sqlite by sea-orm-cli?

Tags: sqlite, rust, sea-orm

I'm using the `sea-orm` library to manage my database. The `uuid()` and `date_time()` types are part of the `sea-orm` migration syntax. When `sea-orm` generates the entities from the SQLite database, `uuid()` and `date_time()` get converted into `String`.

Should I change these types on the entities manually for some other type if I want them to be type-checked? How can I do that? What types can I use? Will I have to convert them back to `String` when importing data into the database? How can I do that?